# VBA excel to copy formula from a worksheet and paste to multiple worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, loops, copy-paste

VBA excel to copy formula from a sheet and paste to an array of worksheets.  As an example, I want to copy data from worksheet Data!C4:CX204 and paste to worksheets Test1:Test50.  The Worksheets from Test1:Test50 will be right after each other.  I was thinking I can name one cell Test1 and another Test 50 and link to those cells in order to make the array more flexible.

```
Sub Button4_Click() 
Dim WS_Count As Integer 
Dim I As Integer 

WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count 

Dim Source As Range 
Set Source = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("C10") 

' Begin the loop. 
For I = 1 To WS_Count 
    ThisWorkbook.worksheets(i).Select ' just select the sheet 
    Source.Copy Range("C11:C300").Select 
    ActiveSheet.Paste 
Next I 

End Sub
```

Comment: What VBA code have you tried?

Comment: I don't have any experience with VBA.  I saw some things on line but the thing that was missing from most of the code was the ability to choose the array of worksheets.  Most codes were there to choose ALL sheets.  See below as an example.

Comment: Sub Button4_Click()

Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim I As Integer
WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

Dim Source As Range

Set Source = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("C10")

' Begin the loop.
For I = 1 To WS_Count

    ThisWorkbook.worksheets(i).Select ' just select the sheet
    Source.Copy    
    Range("C11:C300").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

Next I

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code you posted, you probably want something like this:

```
Sub Button4_Click()
Dim src As Range, sel As Range
Dim i as long

Set sel = Selection
Set src = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("C10")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

For i = 1 to 50
    src.Copy ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Test" & i).Range("C11:C300")
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Application.Goto sel, False

End Sub
```

Comment: The problem I'm having with this code is that it is copy and pasting to all the sheets in the workbook.  I would like it to only do a specific amount of tabs i.e. range tabs Test1:Test50 , a total of 50 tabs

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?  The i = 1 to worksheets count can be changed to what ever you need.  The second part of the copy/paste is the destination.

```
Sub Button4_Click()
Dim I As Integer

' Begin the loop.
For I = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count - 1
Worksheets(1).Range("C11:C300").Copy Worksheets("Test" & I).Range("C11:C300")
Next I

End Sub
```

Comment: The test1:test50 was actually just an example, but yes I believe in that situation it would work perfect.  Thanks Mooseman - appreciate your help, I'll see if I can incorporate your method for another worbook

Comment: As long as the sheets have a number you can increment or you could use the Sheets number to reference which sheet gets pasted to.

Comment: You are welcome,. Pick an answer and upvote the answers that helped.