# Copy data to different sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have data in sheet1 from B2:G17, (has formulas). This table should be to copied to other 50 sheets. The below code copies the values but not the formulas. How do I modify the code to copy the formulas in these cells?

```
Sub CopyPasteLoop()

Dim vRange As Variant
vRange = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B2:G17")

Dim i As Integer
For i = 2 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Range("B2:G17").Value = vRange
Next i

End Sub
```

The formulas are dependent on the data in the individual sheets.

Comment: Either copy and paste the formulae or store the formulae in the array.

Comment: I used the code at

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842369/vba-excel-to-copy-formula-from-a-worksheet-and-paste-to-multiple-worksheets

I mofiied the code according to my needs.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This [link to a previous question may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842369/vba-excel-to-copy-formula-from-a-worksheet-and-paste-to-multiple-worksheets)

I think you can use replace the line in your loop with something like

src.Copy ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Range("B2:G17")

I hope this helps some.

Comment: I used the code at

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842369/vba-excel-to-copy-formula-from-a-worksheet-and-paste-to-multiple-worksheets

I mofiied the code according to my needs.

Thanks for the help.